# I use crispy-forms work in django,render failures after the first click the submit button,the second time click the submit button has no response

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am ready to use crispy-froms to my django projection,but in the test,there happen a question,I do not know where happened mistakes.So I post the code here.
If someone can point out the mistake,I will appreciate it.
forms:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(),label='Name',max_length=100,)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Button('save', 'save'))
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_id = 'pkg-form'

        class Meta:
            model = PkgList
            fields = (
                'id','name',
             )
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^testform/$',test_form,name='test_form')
```

the views in my code:

```
@json_view
def test_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'and request.is_ajax():
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return {'success': True}
        else:
            form_html = render_crispy_form(form)
            return {'success': False, 'form_html': form_html}

    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            form = TestForm()
            return render(request,'man/pkg_form.html',{'form':form})
```

templetes:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <div class="modal-content message_align">
        <div class="modal-body" align="center">
            <span class="section">Pkg Info</span>
            {% crispy form form.helper%}
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

```
$('#button-id-save').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = '#pkg-form';
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'pkg_view' %}",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if (!(data['success'])) {
                $(form).replaceWith(data['form_html']);
            }else {
                window.location.href = "{%url 'man/pkglist'  %}";
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $(form).find('.error-message').show()
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

after the first ajax POST and return {'success': False, 'form_html': form_html} from the backend,click the button can not send ajax POST no more.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's because your ajax event is bind to an element which is being replaced by the returned data. Try binding it to document.

Instead of

```
$('#button-id-save').on('click', function(event){ ... }
```

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", "#button-id-save", function(event){
  ...
});
```